# how to write rows one by one in an excel file using python web crawling

Tags: python, web-crawler

I want to write an excel file with data that I got through a website (cnn.com). I did write an excel file but it is not worked the way I want.

Because I want to save data **page by page** as rows.

so the result I've got now looks like this - 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK8Ml.png)

and the ideal result looks like this -
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SzcK.png)

So here is my code. Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from bs4 import NavigableString
import re

path = "/Users/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

# select tag in several pages

a =['world','politics','business','entertainment','sport','health','videos']
nl = []
for i in a:
    driver.get("https://edition.cnn.com/"+str(i))
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    find_ingre = soup.select("div.cd__content")
    for i in find_ingre:
        nl.append(i.get_text())


from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Append all results as row
ws.append(nl)
wb.save("newstopic.xlsx")
```

Comment: Hint: check `if` new page, put `\n`.

Comment: Hint2/bug: You are using the i-variable in your for-loop twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of appending the list to worksheet at the end add it in the every iteration. Try the below code it will work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from bs4 import NavigableString
import re
import xlsxwriter
from openpyxl import Workbook

path = "/Users/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

# select tag in several pages

a =['world','politics','business','entertainment','sport','health','videos']
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for i in a:
    nl = []
    driver.get("https://edition.cnn.com/"+str(i))
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    find_ingre = soup.select("div.cd__content")
    for i in find_ingre:
        nl.append(i.get_text())
    ws.append(nl)

wb.save("newstopic.xlsx")
```